# Overridden methods or properties when project not referenced

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider a solution with the following properties:

The solution contains three projects **A**, **B** and **C**

- Each of these projects contain a single class **ClassA**, **ClassB** and **ClassC**.
- Project **B** has a reference to project **A**
- **ClassB** inherits from **ClassA**
- **ClassB** overrides the method `DoStuff()` from **Class A**
- Project **C** has a reference to project **A** but not to project **B**.

At runtime, a method in **ClassC** receives an object as a parameter which is an instance of **ClassB**. The method that receives the parameter calls `DoStuff()` on the object. The compiler wouldn't let me call any non overridden methods in **ClassB** because I don't have a reference to it. However, the compiler will allow a call to `DoStuff()` because of the reference to project A. My question is, at runtime, will the base class method be called or will it call the derived class method. My testing suggests the derived class, but is it safe to assume this will always work?

Note, the question is specifically asked about C# but I imagine the answer would be similar across most languages.

Comment: `At runtime, a method in ClassC receives an object as a parameter which is an instance of ClassB.` this suggests that `C` is not the entry point to the app. What is the entry point project? that will answer your question

Comment: @zaitsman Let's consider both cases. ie, when C is the entry point, and when it isn't.

Comment: If C is entry point, you won't be able to pass an instance of `ClassB` anywhere because it is not known to C. So e.g. if `C` is your actual executable or web app or sth, and it doesn't reference `B` then any deserialization etc. will just fail because this type is not known.

If C is not entry point, and whatever is references both B and C then clearly `ClassB` can be passed as `ClassA` to `ClassC` and through polymorphism `ClassC` can call any `ClassA` declarations on `ClassB` instance; further, you can use reflection to find and call any methods of `ClassB`, you just can't compile them